# Installing man pages on FreeNAS

Tags: freebsd, package-management, freenas, pfsense, freebsd-ports

I'm using pfSense and FreeNAS, both freeBSD derivatives. On the former there isn't sysinstall either, and on both, man pages (base system and ports) aren't installed. How do I install the complete man set from cli?

Answer (score 0):

As far as FreeNAS is concerned at least, from what I've been led to believe it is not possible. However, if you try to access documentation from the GUI, you should find success.

N00b's response [here](https://forums.freenas.org/index.php?threads/include-the-man-pages-so-they-can-be-reached-via-the-cli.17107/) details how you can accomplish this with a jail and set up an alias to do most of the heavy lifting for you once everything is set up.